# Dynamic delete record from Row vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this below requirement where i am displaying opportunityteammember of its related Opportunity.

In the vf page i am dynamically adding opportunityteammember records to its opportunity.

I need to also remove selected opportunityteammember record from vf page row and database.From the vf page row i am able to remove, but i am unable to remove it from database.

Below is the wrapper class and delete method -

```
public List<InnerOpps> wrappers{get;set;}
public void deleteTeamMember () { 

        List<OpportunityTeamMember> OppTeamToDel = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<Wrappers.size();i++){
            OpportunityTeamMember oppToDel = Wrappers[i].oppTeam;
            system.debug('@@@@' + oppToDel);
            if(Wrappers[i].wrapperId==wrapperId){
               wrappers.remove(i);
               OppTeamToDel.add(wrappers[i].oppTeam);
            }
        }
        delete OppTeamToDel;
    }
```

wrapper class -

```
 public class InnerOpps{    

    public OpportunityTeamMember testTeam{get;set;}
    public String wrapperId{get;set;}

    public InnerOpps(OpportunityTeamMember  oppTeamMem){
        oppTeam=oppTeamMem;
        Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
        String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
        wrapperId = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);

    }


    }
```

vf page -

```
<apex:page controller="OppoTeam" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form >  
     <apex:pageBlock > 
     <apex:pageBlock id="pg">

         <apex:pageblocktable value="{!wrappers}" var="var" columns="4" > 

         <apex:column headerValue="Action">


                    <apex:actionRegion >
                                        <apex:commandButton value="Del" action="{!deleteTeamMember}" reRender="pg">
                        <apex:param name="wrapperId" value="{!var.wrapperId}" assignTo="{!wrapperId}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                           </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:column>   


            <apex:column headerValue="Team Member">
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!var.testTeam.Id != null}">
                    {!var.testTeam.Name}
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:column>

         </apex:pageBlockTable>
         <apex:commandButton action="{!addTeamMember}" value="Add" reRender="pg"/> 
         </apex:pageBlock>                                 
      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies here

```
if(Wrappers[i].wrapperId==wrapperId){
    wrappers.remove(i);  
    OppTeamToDel.add(wrappers[i].oppTeam);
}
```

and if we narrow it down further, this line of code, `wrappers.remove(i);`, suggests that you are removing the oppTeamMembers from the wrapper before they are being part of the list. If you debug that particular line, you might get the **index out of bound** error, since `wrapper[i]` is no longer valid if it had only one item.

Try something like this

```
if(Wrappers[i].wrapperId==wrapperId){
    OppTeamToDel.add(wrappers[i].oppTeam);
    wrappers.remove(i);         
}
```